# Not adding to the variable “breakpin”

Tags: lua

I was creating a piece of code to attempt to crack into a program that I created, but it keeps printing out “1” instead of adding 1 to the value every time. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
local breakpin = 0

repeat
    local breakpin = 1 + breakpin
    print(breakpin)
    if breakpin == pin then
        success = true
    end
until success == true
```

Comment: Each definition `local breakpin` introduces new variable with the same name

Comment: How can I combat that then?

Comment: Do not introduce the second variable.  Remove "local" from `local breakpin = 1 + breakpin`